# System.Windows.Automation does not exist in my namespace

Tags: c#

I'm trying to `using System.Windows.Automation;` in my VS 2022 Windows Form C# App, and I keep recieving this error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Automation' does not exist in the namespace 
'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   FinalUI  
C:\Users\me\Documents\Freeze Icon Projects\Test me PC Files\Final UI\Final 
UI\ArrangeIconsProgram.cs   2   Active
```

I tried referencing it, but still recieve this error. This error causes approx 20 other errors in my code.
The code worked fine as an independent console app, but now that I'm in a Windows Form app (trying to make code into software) it does not work.

Comment: Do you resolve compiler errors first to last?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried referencing it". Is it in the list of references now, or not?

Comment: Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window and select "Edit project file".  Add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're seeing suggests that the namespace System.Windows.Automation is not being recognized in your Windows Forms C# application.

You can follow these steps:

```
Right-click on your project in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and select "Manage NuGet Packages".

In the NuGet Package Manager, search for "UIAutomationClient" and install the package.

Make sure you have the correct version of the package that matches your project target framework.

After installing the package, rebuild your project to ensure that the references are properly resolved.
```